# Change detailview according to masterview in UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

[image]

I have a `UISplitViewController` which has a `searchfiled` in the first row of its master view which is a `tableview` as we all know.

And my detail view contains a `collectionview`. I have to update my `collectionviewcells` according to the `seacrhfield` text. So how i update `collectionview` cells just when editing begins in searchfield.
I want to show a `activityindicator` too when user started searching.

So basically i want to control `DetailViewVontroller`'s properties from `MasterViewController's` class whenever i want. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`[self.view addSubview:lbl]`

to add the label to your tableview controller's view.

If you want to replace the view controller, 
take a look at the `showDetailViewController:sender:` method in this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/index.html